# android studio not able to generate signed apk

Tags: android

Am facing a strange issue, am able to run my apps correctly  in debug mode but not able to generate signed apk for any of my android studio projects. am getting the following error.

```
Error:Error: Style Resource definition cycle:  TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title => TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title => TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title [ResourceCycle]
```

what does this mean? am using 23.0.2 as my build tools version and have com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 dependency.

Comment: Is this the whole error log?

Comment: yes this is the only error and it stops generating signed apk.. but am able to debug on real device without any issues

Comment: Generating signed apk tends to be more strict than regular installation. I actually do not know nothing about this error, seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED] - I was giving the wrong 'solution' at first and then proposing the correct one.

For those, like me, that prefer not to change abortOnError flag, it seems like updating appcompat version works for some people. The version is:
So the **other solution** is to update app compat version to:

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2
```

[The following is not recommended, since it is not a solution. It just ignores the build errors]

You can add this to your app's build.gradle:

```
android {
    // your android stuff (compileSdkVersion...)
    //Important for generating apk besides error
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    // your dependencies
}
```

This is a **temporary** solution, but should work. I've read that this is probably an error on the version 23.x of appcompat, so you should update it and **remove** those lintOptions when the update is done.

Comment: I believe that app compat version that solves this is: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2

Comment: am able to generate signed apk but i must update the appcompat version instead of this as making lintoptions false is not a good option i think so.. anyways thanks for your solution

Comment: I'll edit my answer with the option of changing appcompat version, so it might be helpful to others as well